# How to send form value to node/express to search database?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, expr

I've got a pre populated form with gps coordinates and I am trying to search a database.

```
<form>

<mat-toolbar  color="primary">

  <mat-toolbar-row style="justify-content: center;" id="test">  Yonder   </mat-toolbar-row>
 <br>


  <mat-toolbar-row style="justify-content: center;">  <input id="geoSearch" type="text" value="{{coords}}">  </mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-toolbar-row style="justify-content: center;">    <button type="submit" class="subMitButton" id="location-button" mat-raised-button onclick="window.location.reload();" color="accent"> Locate </button>   </mat-toolbar-row>


</mat-toolbar>
<br>


</form>
```

and my backend code

```
app.get('/api/animals',(req, res, next) => {

Animal.find({})
.then(documents => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'success',
    animals: documents
  });
});
```

How can I send the data from the form to be used in the find query?

Thanks!

Comment: onclick="window.location.reload();....?

Comment: use angulars `http` to make an ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HttpClient to make the request to your endpoint. In this case you could have something like:

```js
public response: any;

constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

public makeRequest(): void {
  this.http.get('XXXXXXXXX/api/animals').subscribe((response) => {
    this.response = response;
    // console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Where XXXXXXXXXXXX is your api base url (probably something like http://localhost:3000)

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea of using the http request but how do I capture the data I enter in the search field?

Comment: @HMCS in that case you need to use something like a `formControl` on the input field to grab the value of the field. Make sure you have added `ReactiveFormsModule` to imports in you `App.Module.ts` file, and then on your component use `<input id="geoSearch" type="text" [formControl]="myControl">`. In the ts file add a variable `public myControl: FormControl = new FormControl('')` and now all you need to access the value in the input is `this.myControl.value`. Hope this helps